# Extract everything within the jar

Tags: java, jar, export

The question was probably asked but unfortunately I can't find a viable answer for myself.

I programmed a game, and I exported a runnable jar for it, it works, but I hate the fact that everything is inside this one jar, for example when I would want to update the game for everyone, they will need to re-download the whole jar, which is large, instead of downloading the updated texture, library, or whatever only.

Any idea on - how do I transform my runnable jar to lots of folders, with which I can effectively update the game for people, instead of re-downloading the whole jar in every update?

Comment: Why are you putting everything into one jar in the first place instead of having separate jars for each piece of library code?  If you did that you could just deploy (for instance) the texture jar when you have a new texture.

Comment: Distribute your .jar using [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/), and provide updates as jardiff files (possibly using [JnlpDownloadServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html)).  Web Start also allow you to serve your .jar file compressed with Pack2000 or gzip.